# Sequential calls with nodejs + postgres

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await, sequential

I've tried to call 2 queries toward postgres with nodeJS in a sequential way. I came to this code. 
However I'm not really happy with it, it seems overcomplicated to do a simple thing. Is there a simpler way to do what I'm trying to do ?

Basically, I try to print "before 1st" on console then execute the select now(), then print the results, then write "after 1st", then print "before 2nd" then execute select now(), then print the results, then write "after 2nd"

```js
getConn().
then(async() => {
  console.log("before 1st selectNow2")
  await selectNow2()
  console.log("after 1st selectNow2")
})
.then(async() => {
  console.log("before 2nd selectNow2")
  await selectNow2()
  console.log("after 2nd selectNow2")
})

async function selectNow2() {
  await client.query('SELECT NOW()')
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.rows[0])
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err.stack)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use `await` and `then()` in the same statement inside `selectNow2()`. Since you are using `await`, you will not be returning a promise which means the returned value will not have the method then().

```
performQuery().then(() => {
  console.log("DONE");
});

async function performQuery(){
   await getConn();
   console.log("before 1st selectNow2");
   await selectNow2();
   console.log("after 1st selectNow2");
   console.log("before 2nd selectNow2");
   await selectNow2();
   console.log("after 2nd selectNow2");
}

async function selectNow2) {
  try{
    await client.query('SELECT NOW()');
    console.log(res.rows[0])
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err.stack)
  }
}
```

Comment: async function always returns a promise, so the code will work and I do not see a reason why you cannot do .then(async ...) [EDIT]: Anyway code is good, but I think, it should be explained why it is the same as example in question

Comment: i meant you do not need to chain `.then()` if you are using await.

Comment: As he mentioned in the question. His answer is correct but need another format. and that's what i did.

Comment: Thanks for those answers!